# ORCA finished by error termination in SCF gradient

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orca

I try to optimize and compute frequencies for the system built up from C, O, H, and Co atoms in the following functionals: **B2PLYP, B2PLYP-D3, B3LYP, B3LYP-D3, BLYP, BLYP-D3, DSD-PBEP86, PBE, PBE-D3, WB97X-D3**.
The basis set I use is **aug-cc-pVTZ aug-cc-pVTZ/C def2/J** with **SDD** on Co.
The input is common and looks like that:

```
! BLYP D3ZERO aug-cc-pVTZ aug-cc-pVTZ/C def2/J verytightopt freq
%basis
    newECP Co "SDD" end
end
%geom
%MAXCORE 3428
%PAL NPROCS 28 END
* xyzfile 1 1 BLYP-D3.xyz
```

In each case I got an error:

```
Nuc. rep. gradient       (SHARK) ... done (  0.0 sec)
HCore & Overlap gradient (SHARK) ... done ( 32.0 sec)
ECP gradient             (SHARK) ... done ( 47.0 sec)
RI-J gradient            (SHARK) ... 
ORCA finished by error termination in SCF gradient
Calling Command: mpirun -np 28  /home/users/john/orca503/orca_5_0_3_linux_x86-64_shared_openmpi411/orca_scfgrad_mpi BLYP-D3.scfgrad.inp BLYP-D3 
[file orca_tools/qcmsg.cpp, line 465]: 
  .... aborting the run
```

I use single node, which has 2 processors, each 14 cores (2x14) and up to 128GB. The queue system is SLURM and hence I specify there:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=28
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=28
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=128000MB
```

Comment: This could just be my unfamiliarity with Orca input, but what is aug-cc-pvtz/c? It seems like aug-cc-pvtz is the basis set (for C, H, and O) and def2/J is an auxiliary basis. Based on the error message, it seems to be failing during RI gradients, so something about the basis specification may be wrong. Have you tried running this without def2/J just to see if it still gives an error?

Comment: [Cross posted](https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/v1nlho/orca_finished_by_error_termination_in_scf_gradient/) on Reddit

Comment: +1 on Tyberius's comment, although I would recommend removing aug-cc-pvtz/c instead, because ground state RI calculations require a /J auxiliary basis set, rather than a /C one. If you provide a /C basis when the program does not require it, this may confuse the program. (Ultimately, for the results to be reliable, one may have to use AutoAux instead of def2/J because def2/J is not designed to work well with aug-cc basis sets)

Comment: @Tyberius : Will check that

Comment: @wzkchem5: unfortunatelly autoaux leads to linear dependencies and so I cannot use it. Gonna see if removing /C will fix

Comment: @Tyberius: Did in accordance to your suggestion but still fails!

Comment: I think you can try the aug-cc-pvtz/JK basis sets instead of the def2/J basis sets. They will not provide linear dependency, and are quite large so I imagine errors won't be high. (Even though they are designed for JK-fitting, not J-fitting). And also try removing the ECP and see if the code works. Also try the old libint integral driver instead of SHARK, by using `! NoShark`

Comment: This might be totally unrelated, but shouldn't nprocs be the same as ntasks? I don't remember the details, so how do you calculate maxcore? Looks low. It's been a while for me to do these calculations, but I remember that there was a lot of guidance in the input library. Look at the statistics of slurm to see what is actually used. And is probably a good idea to leave out anything you don't need, like running a Freq job it you are struggling with scf.

Comment: @SRMaiti Unfortunatelly, aug-cc-pVTZ/JK is not for Co atom I have within a structure... Computing Co without ECP? That would be quite much demanding as I think. Will definitely check NoShark !

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes, i have changed nprocs to 28 - at the begining I though nprocs == number of processors... however seems like it is number of processes.

Comment: Here is output from the file gathering all the errors  https://pastebin.com/hRqY10mK

Comment: When I use Orca (in rare cases...) I just launch "orca", not (sub)programs such as "orca_scfgrad_mpi" in your case. Could it be the reason of the crash? Why submitting orca_scfgrad_mpi? HTH

Comment: Your program is running into segmentation violation. Could you try increasing maxcore and reducing the number of cores (and keep the SLURM memory allocation fixed)? 28 cores seems really large, but maybe you have a large system.

Comment: Dear All, thank you for your kind answers. I was able to contact ORCA developers and they confirmed the problem is internal. They are going to fix in next update.

Comment: @SRMaiti Do you know if this was fixed in the latest update? I'm curious if we could get this question answered to reflect that update, or at least a community wiki answer with a link pointing to the place where it was confirmed that this was an "internal" problem.

Comment: @NikeDattani Sorry, I don't know.